# ¿Cómo acceder a la cantidad de elementos y suma de duración?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo un objeto con un array de objetos dentro. El requerimiento me pide poder determinar:

1. Duración total del disco, es decir, sumar todas las canciones.
2. Duración promedio de las canciones, es decir, un promedio entre todas las duraciones.
3. La cantidad total de discos.
4. La cantidad total de canciones.

Intenté acceder al índice `album` con un `for...in`, pero luego no se cómo acceder a los valores del array y, posteriormente, de nuevo a los valores para poder sumar las duraciones y los valores. Este es mi código:

```js
const banda = {
  name: "Led Zeppelin",
  year: 1968,
  active: false,
  thumbnail:
    "http://townsquare.media/site/295/files/2014/10/Led-Zeppelin1.jpg?w=980&q=75",
  members: ["Jimmy Page", "Robert Plant", "John Paul Jones", "John Bonham"],
  albums: [
    {
      name: "Led Zeppelin",
      year: 1969,
      songs: ["Good Times, Bad Times", "Communication Breakdown"],
      duration: 2691,
    },
    {
      name: "Led Zeppelin II",
      year: 1969,
      songs: ["Whole Lotta Love", "Moby Dick", "Ramble On"],
      duration: 2502,
    },
    {
      name: "Led Zeppelin III",
      year: 1970,
      songs: ["Immigrant Song"],
      duration: 2489,
    },
    {
      name: "Led Zeppelin IV",
      year: 1971,
      songs: ["Rock and Roll", "Stairway to Heaven", "Four Sticks"],
      duration: 2559,
    },
  ],
};

//Mi intento fue acceder al valor con un forin y luego al array con un for
for (const key in banda.albums) {
  for (let index = 0; index < banda.albums.length; index++) {
    console.log("a")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es:

- duración total del disco, es decir, sumar todas las canciones.
- duración promedio de las canciones, es decir, un promedio entre todas las duraciones.
- la cantidad total de discos.
- la cantidad total de canciones.

---

Entonces, primero vamos a inicializar las variables que utilizaremos en los cálculos:

```js
let totalCanciones = 0; // total de las canciones por album.
let totalDuracion = 0; // total de duración.
let cantidadDiscos = 0; // total de discos.
let duracionPromedio = 0; // promedio de duración de los discos.
```

Luego accedemos a los elementos del array `albums` con `for...in`:

```js
for (const key in banda.albums) {
  const album = banda.albums[key];
}
```

Y como cada elemento del array `albums` es un objeto (con los atributos `name`, `year`, `song` y `duration`), tenemos la libertad de ingresar a sus atributos de cada uno de ellos y sus valores. Con esto, ya podemos hacer las operaciones y almacenarlas en sus respectivas variables, por ejemplo:

```js
for (const key in banda.albums) {
  const album = banda.albums[key];
  totalCanciones += album.songs.length; // mido su longitud de "songs" en cada iteración (en cada objeto), y la suma de ellos almacenados en "totalCanciones".
  totalDuracion += album.duration; // obtengo el valor de "duration" de cada objeto, la suma de ellos almacenados en "totalDuracion".
  cantidadDiscos = banda.albums.length; // obtengo la longitud de elementos del array "albums", que sería la cantidad de discos, asignada a "cantidadDiscos".
}
```

Y lo último vendría a ser el promedio. Recuerda que hasta aquí ya tendríamos el total de duración de los discos y el total de canciones, tendríamos que dividirlos así:

```js
duracionPromedio = totalDuracion / totalCanciones;
```

---

#### Código final:

```js
const banda = {
  name: "Led Zeppelin",
  year: 1968,
  active: false,
  thumbnail:
    "http://townsquare.media/site/295/files/2014/10/Led-Zeppelin1.jpg?w=980&q=75",
  members: ["Jimmy Page", "Robert Plant", "John Paul Jones", "John Bonham"],
  albums: [
    {
      name: "Led Zeppelin",
      year: 1969,
      songs: ["Good Times, Bad Times", "Communication Breakdown"],
      duration: 2691,
    },
    {
      name: "Led Zeppelin II",
      year: 1969,
      songs: ["Whole Lotta Love", "Moby Dick", "Ramble On"],
      duration: 2502,
    },
    {
      name: "Led Zeppelin III",
      year: 1970,
      songs: ["Immigrant Song"],
      duration: 2489,
    },
    {
      name: "Led Zeppelin IV",
      year: 1971,
      songs: ["Rock and Roll", "Stairway to Heaven", "Four Sticks"],
      duration: 2559,
    },
  ],
};

let totalCanciones = 0; // total de las canciones por album.
let totalDuracion = 0; // total de duración.
let cantidadDiscos = 0; // total de discos.
let duracionPromedio = 0; // promedio de duración de los discos.

for (const key in banda.albums) {
  // accedo a los elementos del array "album", que vendrían a ser objetos.
  const album = banda.albums[key];
  // accedo al atributo "song" (que es un array) y sumo su cantidad de elementos del array "songs" en cada elemento del array "album", almacenado en "totalCanciones".
  totalCanciones += album.songs.length;
  // accedo al atributo "duration" y sumo todos sus valores, almacenado en "totalDuracion".
  totalDuracion += album.duration;
  // accedo al array "albums" y asigno su longitud a la variable "cantidadDiscos".
  cantidadDiscos = banda.albums.length;
}

// El promedio sería el total de duración entre el total de canciones.
duracionPromedio = totalDuracion / totalCanciones;

// Imprimimos los valores.
console.log("Duración total del disco: ", totalDuracion);
console.log("Duración promedio de las canciones: ", duracionPromedio);
console.log("Cantidad total de discos: ", cantidadDiscos);
console.log("Cantidad total de canciones: ", totalCanciones);
```